# regex trim pipe separator

Tags: bash, unix, awk

i have a pipe delimited file that looks like this:

```
123| ste hen| 456| out put 
143 | ste hen| 456| out put
```

i want to delete the spaces--- something like this

```
123,ste hen,456,out put
143,ste hen,456,out put
```

this is my code but dont works..

```
 awk '{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"|"); gsub(/ *, */,"|")}1'  test2.txt
```

Comment: Do you want the `|`s changed to `,`s too? If not then please fix your example.

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
123| ste hen| 456| out put 
143 | ste hen| 456| out put
```

then

```
awk '{gsub(/ *\| */,",");print}' file.txt
```

output

```
123,ste hen,456,out put 
143,ste hen,456,out put
```

Changes done as compared to `{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"|"); gsub(/ *, */,"|")}1`

- eliminated `^` i.e. begin
- eliminated `$` i.e. end
- escaped `|` as you need literal `|` not alternative
- looking for zero or more (`*`) spaces around each `|` rather than at least 1 at each side
- replaced two `gsub`s with single one
- trigger printing by `print` rather `1` (matter of style, consult style guide of your organization to use solution appropriate in your case)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

My very first and fast approach is the next one:

```sh
cat testFile.txt | sed 's/|/,/g' | sed 's/\s*,\s*/,/g''
```

The past command display the following result:

```
123,ste hen,456,out put 
143,ste hen,456,out put
```

from the following input:

```
123| ste hen| 456| out put 
143 | ste hen| 456| out put
```

Comment: uuuuhm, so just `sed 's/\s*|\s*/,/g''`

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; s/ *| */,/g' file
```

Answer (score -1):

awk '{gsub(/ *| */, "|");print}' test2.txt

Comment: Maybe this instead: `awk '{ gsub(/ *\| */, ",") } 1' test2.txt`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).